# expanding ploting area so that legends do not overlap

Tags: plot, overlap

I have so many legends in my cca plot that they overlap each other.
I would like to know how to expand plotting region to solve this problem.

my codes go like this:

```
fish=read.csv("cca_correction.csv",header=T,row.names=1)
attach(fish)
n=dim(fish)[[1]];n
y=fish[,7:42];y
x=fish[,1:6];x

library(CCA)
library(vegan)

mod= cca(y ~ W.T.+pH+DO+Cond.+Sal.+Width ,x)
plot(mod)

head(summary(mod), tail=2)
```

Thanks for reading.
Desperately looking forward for your kind answer.

Jung
selly1091@hotmail.com

Answer (score 0):

If you *expand* plotting region, the text will be plotted in the smaller part of the plot, and there will be wider white margins. Probably you want to do something else. As a first aid, check vegandocs("FAQ") for some simple ideas.